# How to cut a specific fragment from a given string

Tags: python

i have one large file and want to extract a fragment of strings from a large file with i have extracted the index position of each string: Example given bellow

```
text = "thisfragmentiwant" 
for i,p in enumerate(text):
      print i,p
```

out put looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
t h i s f r a g m e  n  t  i  w  a  n  t
```

now i want to retrieve "fragment" position 4 to 11, what should be the code i tried a lot but its showing index out of range.

thanks

Comment: What code did you try? `text[4:12]` slices your text perfectly.

Comment: are you always sure in every line the index will always be the same ?

Comment: Show us the input you're using which is giving you the index out of range error or we can't be of much use. In the meantime, check out [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to find the fragment you want and [`re.MatchObject.start` and `re.MatchObject.end`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) to get the indices of the fragment you want. Then use the slice syntax Martijn showed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> text = "thisfragmentiwant" 
>>> text[4 : 12]
'fragment'
```